# How to clear multiple canvas simultaneously?

Tags: html, canvas

I wander if there is a possibility to clear several canvases simultaneously?
I can do that using this bit of code:

```
            button1.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);  
            button2.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
```

But what I am looking for is supposed to look something like this:

```
            button1, button2, button666.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi friend, do you have an actual problem we can help you with?

Comment: Yes  - the problem is that I cannot find the best way to clear several canvases simultaneously. button1.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);  
            button2.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);  button3.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);  
            button4.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);  etc is not a good idea and unfortunately I have 12 contexts to clear.